# LLVM Invalid return type of main() supplied

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing a compiler in OCaml that compiles to LLVM IR. The current program is very simple:

```
num main() {
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it with my compiler, I get the following LLVM IR code:

```
; ModuleID = 'PixMix'
source_filename = "PixMix"

@fmt = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"
@fmt.1 = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%s\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define double @main() {
entry:
  ret double 0.000000e+00
}
```

However, if I pass it to `lli`, I'm told that the return type is invalid. Looking at that code, `main` is defined as a `double` and it's returning a `double`, so why is `lli` telling me that the return type is messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the entry point function (`main` by default, but the name can be controlled by the `-entry-function` flag) is expected to have a certain signature, similar to what `main` looks like in C or C++. In particular, it should either return `void` or an integer type. You can read [the implementation of the check](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/4ab42623aa9ed53700f66f0256685198ece88151/lib/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.cpp#L427) to make sure the IR you generate satisfies it.